# ICommand Weird code

Tags: c#, icommand

I have a question regarding the following piece of code:

```
public void Destroy()
       {
           this.canExecute = _ => false;
           this.execute = _ => { return; };
       }
```

I copy/pasted [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example) regaring the use of ICommands,
but i can't figure out why the author chose to put his this way.

Why not just:

```
this.canExecute = false;
```

Comment: The type of `canExecute` is `Predicate<object>`. Have you tried assigning a `bool` value to a variable of that type?

Comment: That's because its type is [Predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Aah thanks! I looked it up and i understand now.
Thanks for the help guys! I was confused because another class I've just written had the same property of type bool ;)

Comment: Far more funny is the `{ return; }`-statement. Simply use `= _ => { }`.

Comment: I figured, so it's just there for readability?

Comment: Eeehm, no, a boolean is completely different from a `Predicate`, which is a *delegate*. You should definitly read some basics on delegates.